# how to submit ajax form on same page in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress, I want a customize form, so I created this form where user can input data from front end. But when I submit this form, if it is successful, Within `<div id="feedback"></div>`, whole page has been shown again. Because of I get all "data" in the ajax success or error function. How can I get only data which is in echo??

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Complain
*/
get_header();
?>

<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
    global $wpdb;

    $complain_name = $_POST['complain_name'];  

    if($wpdb->insert(
            'wp_complain',
            array(
                'name'=>$complain_name                   
            )
        )==false) {
        echo 'Database insertion failed';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Database insertion successful';
    }
}
else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">

           Name <input type="text" id="complain_name" class="form-control" name="complain_name" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>            

            <input class="btn btn-block" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){

            $("form").on('submit',(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //heresome other functions for validation

                    formData =new FormData(this)
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'<?php echo content_url(); ?>/themes/abc/complain-detail.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData ,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {                               
                                $('#feedback').html(data)                               
                        },
                        error: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#feedback').html(data)
                        }
                    });
                }

            ));

        })
    </script>

    <?php
}
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: try to use `die("...");` instead of `echo "....";`, also use `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"]))`

Comment: Good idea @MamdouhFreelancer! A `die();` at the complete end of `if($_POST['submit']) {` would do. And it is better than my answer (which I just removed).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`die("....");`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) instead of `echo "....";` witch will stop your PHP code at this line, So your HTML won't be shown.

```
if( isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"]) ){

      if(inserted)
           die("Database insertion successful"); //PHP will stop here
      else
           die("Database insertion failed"); //or here

}

  //Your HTML won't be shown ...
```

Comment: You should maybe clarify what you mean by `if(inserted)`. I understand you mean "your condition to determine if database insert succeded"... But I had a small brain-lag on it... ;) +1 for this clean solution.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form-horizontal");
const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new ForData();
  
  data.append("complain_name",document.querySelector(".form-control").value);
  ajax.open("POST",'<?php echo content_url(); ?>/themes/abc/complain-detail.php');
  ajax.send(data);
  
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    
    document.querySelector(".feedback").textContent = "Thanks for your feedback.";
  
  }else{
        document.querySelector(".feedback").textContent = "Sorry,something when wrong,please try again later.";
  }
  
});
```

```html
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">

           Name <input type="text" id="complain_name" class="form-control" name="complain_name" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>            

            <input class="btn btn-block" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This will say "Thanks for your feedback." even if the PHP has sent a "Database insertion failed". It only show the ajaxcall is successfull whatever the answer from the database is.

Comment: Yes if because the AJAX feedback only care about where is successfully send the request or not,it won't care about your server side problem